# Angular $http POST parsing JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my mobile, angular app i try to send a JSON object to the server for further processing.

This is my JSON

```
$sessionsString = {"ojoijoj":[{"station":"AABB","height":80,"period":"20","gsh":"1.11","gsp":"20","gsd":"225","wsh":"1.11","wsp":"5.3","wsd":"270","dt":"2015-07-08T00:00:00.000Z","station2":"9410230","windStrength":"3.6","windDirection":"220","tideHeightInCM":115.06811989101},{"station":"CCBB","height":90,"period":"10","gsh":"1.7","gsp":"10","gsd":"207.5","wsh":"2.7","wsp":"9.9","wsd":"207.5","dt":"2015-07-16T21:00:00.000Z","station":"94102302","windStrength":"3.17","windDirection":"308.502","tideHeightInCM":83.986622073579}],"y4":[{"station":"DD","height":90,"period":"15","gsh":"1.11","gsp":"15","gsd":"225","wsh":"2.3","wsp":"5","wsd":"297.5","dt":"2015-07-04T19:00:00.000Z","station2":"9410230","windStrength":"1.5","windDirection":"280","tideHeightInCM":134.37293729373}]};`
```

I'm sending my JSON via

```
$http.post(requestURL, {'sessions':JSON.stringify(sessions)}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('Success');
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  });
```

and figured through some other references that I have to get the data through

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

to retrieve the parameters rather than with regular $_POST for some reason. (Found this in other posts, $_POST didnt work -> is this thread safe by the way?)

However, I want to parse the data now, and it doesn't work.

```
$sessionsString = $params['sessions'];
$sessions = json_decode($sessionsString,true);
$spotNames = array_keys($sessions);
```

`array_keys` fails with no keys found. When I directly assign the above JSON string to `$sessionString` it works fine. What's happening? I dont know how to debug this because it's a POST parameter that I can't fully see and the file read out in PHP could be a problem, too.

Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont stringify in `$http` just pass in the object. angular will take care of converting to json

```
$http.post(requestURL, {sessions:sessions})...
```

Also the first `json_decode` should now work without needing the second

Comment: Interesting. I am checking the apache access/error logs and it reports that it recieves two requests. One without parameters and one with all parameters. I am running only one request in the whole app. How could that be?

Comment: is this a cross domain request? Even a different port counts as cross domain. If so, will have an OPTIONS preflight request also

Comment: Does it require a specific answer on the preflight request or is it really just a ping? How shall I deal with that in PHP?

Comment: logs are probably counting the OPTIONS preflight then. It's the preflight that needs the CORS headers or post won't get sent

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are calling `json_decode` twice. Not sure why `$_POST` didn't work for you, but you can always use `var_dump($params)`to see whats happening.

Comment: $_POST doesn't work because angular sends as `application/json` by default not form encoding unless you change request header

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt $_POST to deal with the header in a more streamlined way?

Comment: Well the Content-Type of your post request should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Using angular I believe you can do the following `$http({method:'POST', url:requestURL, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, data:'sessions='+JSON.stringify(sessions)}).success(...)`. Here's a  [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). I believe this should allow you to use $_POST.

Comment: either way works fine. If it's sent in body as json you use what OP is using `file_get_contents()`